# Understanding difference between Double Quote and Single Quote with __repr__()

Tags: python, repr

What is the difference between `print`, `object`, and `repr()`?
Why is it printing in different formats?

See the `output difference`:

```
>>> x="This is New era"
>>> print x             # print in double quote when with print()
This is New era

>>> x                   #  x display in single quote
'This is New era'

>>> x.__repr__()        # repr() already contain string
"'This is New era'"

>>> x.__str__()         # str() print only in single quote ''
'This is New era'
```

Comment: I think  the name x is attached to 'This is New era' string. When I called for example repr(x) the iterpreter puts 'This is New era' instead of x and then called repr('This is New era').

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no semantic difference between `'` and `"`. You can use `'` if the string contains `"` and vice versa, and Python will do the same. If the string contains both, you have to escape some of them (or use triple quotes, `"""` or `'''`). (If both `'` and `"` are possible, Python and many programmers seem to prefer `'`, though.)

```
>>> x = "string with ' quote"
>>> y = 'string with " quote'
>>> z = "string with ' and \" quote"
>>> x
"string with ' quote"
>>> y
'string with " quote'
>>> z
'string with \' and " quote'
```

About `print`, `str` and `repr`: `print` will *print* the given string with no additional quotes, while `str` will *create* a string from the given object (in this case, the string itself) and `repr` *creates* a "representation string" from the object (i.e. the string including a set of quotes). In a nutshell, the difference between `str` and `repr` should be that `str` is easy to understand *for the user* and `repr` is easy to understand *for Python*.

Also, if you enter any expression in the interactive shell, Python will automatically echo the `repr` of the result. This can be a bit confusing: In the interactive shell, when you do `print(x)`, what you *see* is `str(x)`; when you use `str(x)`, what you see is `repr(str(x))`, and when you use `repr(x)`, you see `repr(repr(x))` (thus the double quotes).

```
>>> print("some string") # print string, no result to echo
some string
>>> str("some string")   # create string, echo result
'some string'
>>> repr("some string")  # create repr string, echo result
"'some string'"
```

Comment: I think the name x is attached to 'This is New era' string. When I called for example repr(x) the iterpreter puts 'This is New era' instead of x and then called repr('This is New era').

Comment: `__repr__` is usually constructed in such a way, that when you pass its return value to `eval`, you would receive the exact same object `__repr__` was defined on in the first place. Hence the double quotes around the single-quoted string, as `eval("'My string'")` would work, but `eval('my string')` would raise a `SyntaxError`. See also [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr)

Comment: yeah @karlson ...... eval calculates the result of an expression. The result is always a value (such as a number, a string, or an object)

Answer (score 1):

See [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__):

> Called by the repr() built-in function and by string conversions (reverse quotes) to compute the “official” string representation of an object. **If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value** (given an appropriate environment).

And [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__):

> Called by the str() built-in function and by the print statement to compute the “informal” string representation of an object. **This differs from __repr__() in that it does not have to be a valid Python expression**: a more convenient or concise representation may be used instead.

Emphasis added by me.

Answer (score 0):

`__str__` and `__repr__` are both methods for getting a string representation of an object. `__str__` is supposed to be shorter and more user-friendly, while `__repr__` is supposed to provide more detail.

However, in **python** there is **no difference** between single quote and double quote.